# Parse LogInView Logo Image very small

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, loginview, pfloginviewcontroller

I am building an iOS app using Parse as my backend and Swift for the programming language. In my `viewDidAppear` function, I call the following function:

```
func showLogin() {

    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {

        var logInViewController = PFLogInViewController()
        logInViewController.delegate = self

        var signUpViewController = PFSignUpViewController()
        signUpViewController.delegate = self

        logInViewController.signUpController = signUpViewController

        // Set custom logo in Log In View
        var logoImage = UIImageView()
        logoImage.image = UIImage(named: "myNewLogo")
        logoImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

        logInViewController.logInView?.logo = logoImage

        self.presentViewController(logInViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

But when I do this, the logo on the Parse UI Log In View is moved a lot higher on the view and shrinks the image VERY small!

**How can I set this size and position of the logo?**

**What size and position SHOULD I use to be similar to the standard Parse logo?**

**What size should my IMAGE be? Should I include normal and @2x and @3x sizes?**

Comment: Having higher resolution will make your image bigger. iOS 7 is running on device that minimum supports 2x resolution by default.

Comment: To analyze Parse logo and make it similar, Take a screenshot and analyze ratio of items - position ,and size

Comment: No, this is an issue to do with the size/bounds of the `logInViewController.logInView?.logo` because the UIImageView is set to scaleToFit, so changing image size will not help.